# Comparing confirmatory factor analysis models with different number of observed variables

Tags: model-selection, goodness-of-fit, psychometrics, confirmatory-factor

I have a 14 item scale that is hypothesized to measure self-esteem. The first model I specify uses all 14 items and predicts one latent factor (i.e., self-esteem). I would then like to specify a second (theoretically driven) model than only uses 6 of the 14 items to predict the same single latent construct (i.e., self-esteem). Now I have my two models, and I would like to compare them to find out which is better (in terms of goodness of fit of the data given the number of parameters etc., I assume).

**Is it possible to make legitimate comparisons between the two models, given that each model has a different number of observed variables (and thus parameters)?** If not, are there any other ways to get around this?

Comment: Can you clarify more what the end goal is? It sounds like you are making a short-form scale (though six items is incredibly short) but it doesn't sounds like you are focusing on the relative measurement precision drop at all. It's true the models aren't strictly nested because the data are not, but certain measurement properties will change rather systematically. Model fit generally isn't the issue here when constructing short-forms.